# How to make Eclipse always "Copy projects into workspace"?

Tags: eclipse, import, project

How can I make Eclipse to always `copy projects into workspace`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't force this to be set.

However the setting is remembered between uses, so once you have selected this option it will stay selected until you explicitly deselect it.

Comment: I don't think it works like that. I have to select it to copy to workspace every time. I am using Juno from Android Bundle.